# How to make a script run automatically (daily), commit files that have been changed (by the script) and push to GitHub

Tags: javascript, git, github, npm, automation

A (Nodejs) project of mine uses a json file (say `data.json`) which needs to be updated daily. I update the json file with a script by running `npm run update-data` which changes (updates) the contents of some files. I then stage and commit these changed files, with a specific commit message, and push the commits to GitHub.

The problem is that doing all this manually every day gets too tedious and mechanical. Since all the "steps" are clear and algorithmic, it is best if these are performed automatically. I can, of course, write a bash script that does this, but it is not guaranteed that my computer will be powered on to run it.

So my question: is there an online *something*-as-a-Service that can do all that for me, including staging, committing and pushing to GitHub?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not write the task into a shell script and then just call that shell script from `cron`?

Comment: @Corion I've mentioned this: I can, of course, write a bash script that does this, but it is not guaranteed that my computer will be powered on to run it.

Comment: The "something as a service" is called a VPS and there are lots of them you can rent